# Modelsim "Entity '...' has no architecture." error

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus, hardware

I'm trying to simulate a VHDL project but modelsim gives me the following error message:

```
Error: (vsim-3173) Entity 'C:/Users/chose/Documents/CTD/teste/SELETORES/simulation/modelsim/rtl_work.seletores' has no architecture.
```

I tryed creatindg another project and it gives me the same error. I was able to sim other projects before, doing the same thing.

I'm running Quartus Prime Lite Edition 16.0 and Modelsim 10.5b. The code i'm trying to simulate is:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_Logic_1164.all;

entity SELETORES is
port(   IN_POT: in std_logic;
        OUT_POT, REG_ALARM, REG_OPEN, CONTA, SW
                :   in  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        MODE    :   in  std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
        SEL_DISP, SEL_LED
                :   in      std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        LED_OUT, SEL_TIME, SEL_POT
                :   out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        REG :   out std_logic_vector(19 downto 0)
        );
end SELETORES;

architecture SELETORES_bhv of SELETORES is
    signal decod_mux : std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);

component mux_4x1_20
port (W,X,Y,Z: in std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
        S: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        F: out std_logic_vector(19 downto 0)
      );
end component;

component mux_4x1_10
port (W,X,Y,Z: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        S: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        F: out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
      );
end component;

component mux_2x1
port (W,X: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        S: in std_logic;
        F: out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
      );
end component;

component decod_time
port(   ENTRADA : in    std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        SAIDA: out  std_logic_vector(19 downto 0)
        );
end component;

begin

L1 : mux_4x1_10 port map ("0000000000", REG_OPEN, OUT_POT, REG_ALARM, SEL_LED, LED_OUT);

L2 : mux_2x1 port map (SW, MODE(19 downto 10), SEL_DISP(0) and not(SEL_DISP(1)), SEL_TIME);

L3 : decod_time port map (CONTA, decod_mux);

L4 : mux_4x1_20 port map ("00000110010111101111", MODE(39 downto 20), decod_mux, "11111100011100111101", SEL_DISP, REG);

L5 : mux_2x1 port map (SW, MODE(9 downto 0), IN_POT, SEL_POT);

end SELETORES_bhv;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have some syntax errors in your L2 component instantiation. Secondly, in my opinion this is the right way to do it (operators are not permitted in port maps):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity SELETORES is
port(   IN_POT: in std_logic;
        OUT_POT, REG_ALARM, REG_OPEN, CONTA, SW
                :   in  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        MODE    :   in  std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
        SEL_DISP, SEL_LED
                :   in      std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        LED_OUT, SEL_TIME, SEL_POT
                :   out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        REG :   out std_logic_vector(19 downto 0)
        );
end SELETORES;

architecture SELETORES_bhv of SELETORES is

-- Component declarations

component mux_4x1_20
  port (W,X,Y,Z: in std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
        S1: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        F: out std_logic_vector(19 downto 0)
        );
end component;

component mux_4x1_10
  port (W,X,Y,Z: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        S2: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        F: out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
        );
end component;

component mux_2x1
  port (W,X: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        S3: in std_logic;
        F: out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
        );
end component;

component decod_time
  port(ENTRADA : in    std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
       SAIDA: out  std_logic_vector(19 downto 0)
       );
end component;

--End component declarations

-- Internal signals

signal decod_mux : std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
signal foobar: std_logic;

--End Internal Signals

begin

foobar <= SEL_DISP(0) AND NOT SEL_DISP(1);

L1 : mux_4x1_10 port map ("0000000000", REG_OPEN, OUT_POT, REG_ALARM, SEL_LED, LED_OUT);

L2 : mux_2x1 port map (SW, MODE(19 downto 10), foobar, SEL_TIME);

L3 : decod_time port map (CONTA, decod_mux);

L4 : mux_4x1_20 port map ("00000110010111101111", MODE(39 downto 20), decod_mux, "11111100011100111101", SEL_DISP, REG);

L5 : mux_2x1 port map (SW, MODE(9 downto 0), IN_POT, SEL_POT);

end SELETORES_bhv;
```

I've tested on ModelSim 10.1c with no problems.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe it was that simple. But shouldn't Quartus compiler warn me about something this obvious?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076=2008 I6.5.6.3 Port clauses para 6 *If the actual part of a given association element for a formal port of a block is the reserved word inertial followed by an expression, or is an expression that is not globally static, then the given association element is equivalent to association of the port with an anonymous signal implicitly declared in the declarative region that immediately encloses the block. The signal has the same subtype as the formal port and is the target of an implicit concurrent signal assignment statement of the form anonymous <= E; where E is the expression...*

Comment: @user1155120 Well, unfortunately I haven't dug this deep in the IEEE standard, so my explanation was kinda naive. I bet experience does the trick...